# Calling Restlet client resource from server resource causes HTTP 404 error

Tags: java, restlet, restlet-2.0

I have a Restlet server application that calls client resource for the purpose of hitting a google endpoint.

When I get to the point in my code:

```
ClientResource storeRoot = new ClientResource("http://googleendpoint");
  String jsonString = storeRoot.get().getText();
```

I get the warnings and errors:

> Jan 7, 2013 4:33:34 PM org.restlet.engine.component.ClientRouter
>   getNext WARNING: The protocol used by this request is not declared in
>   the list of client connectors. (HTTPS/1.1). In case you are using an
>   instance of the Component class, check its "clients" property. Not
>   Found (404) - The server has not found anything matching the request
>   URI   at
>   org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:612)

I have googled around and seen that the solution is likely adding the protocol to the endpoint like this:

```
component.getClients​().add(Protocol.HTTPS​);
```

The problem is that I am running this as a war file in tomcat.  Where do I access this component object to add the protocol?

I have also changed my web.xml to support this protocol like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

         <display-name>Restlet adapters</display-name>

         <servlet>
                 <servlet-name>Restlet1</servlet-name>
                 <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
                 <init-param>
                         <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
                         <param-value>com.MyApplication</param-value>
                 </init-param>
                 <init-param>
                    <param-name>org.restlet.clients</param-name>
                    <param-value>HTTP HTTPS FILE</param-value>
                </init-param>
         </servlet>

         <servlet-mapping>
                 <servlet-name>Restlet1</servlet-name>
                 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: At some point in building my app I had that problem and fixed it by adding the following to my web.xml:   [code] <context-param>
  <param-name>org.restlet.clients</param-name>
  <!--  <param-value>CLAP FILE</param-value> -->
  <param-value>CLAP HTTP HTTPS</param-value> 
 </context-param> [code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of heartache I determined that solution was the addition of params in the web.xml that Andy stated above and also the addition of the following jars:

org.restlet.ext.net
org.restlet.ext.httpclient
org.restlet.ext.ssl

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following to your web.xml, inside the `<servlet>` element.

```
<!-- Your application class name -->
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
    <param-value>test.MyApplication</param-value>
</init-param>

<!-- List of supported client protocols -->
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.restlet.clients</param-name>
    <param-value>HTTP HTTPS FILE</param-value>
</init-param>
```

See http://www.restlet.org/documentation/snapshot/gae/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html for more complete documentation.

Comment: I have added this to web.xml but I don't see any change in the error above.  Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Where you have
    <param-value>com.MyApplication</param-value>
that needs to be the full package-scoped name of your class that derives from org.restlet.Application (I'm assuming it's not really called "com.MyApplication", is it?).